# System.UnauthorisedAccessException

Tags: uwp

I was trying to retrieve file names from my local folder while an exception pops out(System.UnauthorisedAccessException)

Tried with lots of solution's but did not work..I granted the user FULL CONTROL from the Folder properties,Run as Administrator etc...

Here is my Code

Class1.cs

```cs
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>> generatename()
{
   ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> newdata = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();
   StorageFolder f2 = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"E:\Videos\Misc");
   List<string> filetypefilter = new List<string>();
   filetypefilter.Add(".mp4");
   QueryOptions query = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, filetypefilter);
   StorageFileQueryResult queryresult = f2.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(query);
   IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryresult.GetFilesAsync();
   try {
        newdata.Add(new GroupInfoList() { Items = files[0].Name });               
       }
   catch(System.UnauthorizedAccessException e) {   }
   return newdata;
}
public async static Task<ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>> GetContacts()
{
   ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> cgroup = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();
   var x = await generatename();
   var query = from item in x
               group item by item.Items[0] into g
               orderby g.Key
               select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };
   foreach (var item in query)
   {
       GroupInfoList c1 = new GroupInfoList();
       c1.Key = item.GroupName;
       foreach (var item2 in item.Items)
       {
           c1.Add(item2);
           //c1.Items = item2.Items;
       }
       cgroup.Add(c1);
   }
   return cgroup;
}
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
   public ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> data { get { return this._data; } }
    public ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> _data;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyView.Source = data; ;
    }
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
       _data = await Class1.GetContacts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps work little different - you can't have direct access to files by path. Your app first need to have [permission to access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) files and folder. There are two ways of acquiring those - by using *File/FolderPickers* and by using libraries, like for example [KnownFolders.VideosLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227159) - for the second option you will need to add suitable capabilites. Once you have a folder with permissions, you should be able to access files inside it.